# How can OpenSSH SSHD log date/time as well?

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I use OpenSSH SSHD in Cygwin under Windows. I start SSHD with option "-e -D" in Registry Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\sshd\Parameters\AppArgs` to enable logging to file `\cygwin64\var\log\sshd.log`. This works nicely.

Unfortunately, the log doesn't contain any date/time information, which is quite unhelpful. :)  Is there any way to enable logging with a timestamp preceeded/appended to each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the sshd logging code, it just doesn't provide that capability.